# How to use jQuery to remove divs containing specific text, as well as the HR divider after only the divs removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

On a page that contains a list of `<div>` blocks, each of which contain location info, and after each `<div>` there is an `<hr>`, I need to target and remove all divs that do not have the city Boston in them.

I was able to easily remove those divs with:
`$("div.location").not(":contains('Boston')").remove();`

That was when I noticed the surplus of leftover `<hr>`

Would it be better to target and remove all of the dividers first? Then the divs? Can I do both with one stroke of jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting how many ways there are to do this syntactically!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div.location").not(":contains('Boston')").next('hr').remove().end().remove();​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KCqqN/3/)***

NOTE to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920240/how-to-use-jquery-to-remove-divs-containing-specific-text-as-well-as-the-hr-div/13920341#comment19188468_13920341)

```
$("div.location").not(":contains('Boston')")  // return the target div
     .next('hr')  // take the pointer to hr, next to target div
     .remove()    // remove the hr
     .end()       // return the pointer to target div.location again
     .remove();​   // remove the target div
```

Comment: Much thanks! Can you tell me specifically what purpose adding `.end()` adds?

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for the thorough breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do both with one stroke of jQuery

Not that it's any "better", but you can always just chain it, remove the `next()` HR, then use `end()` to step back and `remove()` the div, or do it the other way around removing the div first, does'nt really matter much:

```
$('div.location').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Boston') == -1;
}).next('hr').remove().end().remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! I always welcome examples that compare "contains" to "filter."

Answer (score 1):

The obvious one is `$("div.location:not(:contains('Boston')), div.location:not(:contains('Boston')) + hr").remove()​`

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide any insight as to why this would be preferable to `$("div.location").not(":contains('Boston')").next('hr').remove().end().remove();​` ? Thanks!

Comment: May be no overhead for context switching when end() work, but the repeat of complex selector `div.location:not(:contains('Boston'))` may be slow. I'm not sure my method is faster than others.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple selector, then get the conjunctive hr elements left over

```
$("div.location:not(:contains('Boston'))").remove().add("hr+hr").remove();
```

EDIT:
alternate avoid double dom manipulation by direct selection first

```
$("div.location:not(:contains('how'))").add("div.location:not(:contains('how'))+hr").remove();
```